# what is the best pratice of nested dict for mongoengine ODM?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, mongoengine

I have some data like this in my MongoDB:

```
    "FetchedZipSize" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 2,
            "c" : 3,
            "d" : 4,
            "e" : 5
    },
```

how to I modeling it with mongoengine ODM?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [embedded document](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#embedded-documents) field to create a nested structure of dictionaries. Something like this should work:

```
from mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument
class FetchedZipSize(EmbeddedDocument):
    a=IntField()
    b=IntField()

class CollectionName(Document):
    fetchedZipSize = EmbeddedDocumentField(FetchedZipSize)
```